# Error with Timer class when i try do event after current and set time equal

Tags: java, android, timer, alarm

i just want to scan when my time will be equal to current time, and do it use Timer, but when checkbox is clicked and my time equal to current time...it`s get fatal error. Any other solutions?

```
        privae int currentHourOfDay,currentMinutes;
        private int mHourOfDay, mMinutes;
        .....

        chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        chk1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (chk1.isChecked()) {

                h = tv.getText().toString(); //get text from hours input
                m = tv2.getText().toString(); //get text from miutes input
                mHourOfDay = Integer.parseInt(h);
                mMinutes = Integer.parseInt(m);

                System.out.println(mHourOfDay);
                System.out.println(mMinutes);

                final Timer timer = new Timer();

                timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() { 

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                currentHourOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                currentMinutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                System.out.println(currentHourOfDay);
                System.out.println(currentMinutes);

                Integer x = mHourOfDay;
                Integer y = currentHourOfDay;
                Integer x1 = mMinutes;
                Integer y1 = currentMinutes;

                if (x.equals(y) && x1.equals(y1)) {

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Now it equels!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    timer.cancel();

                } 
            }}, 0, 1000);


            } else {
                System.out.println("alarm is off");
            }
        }
    });
```

Mb i have to use some other ways to solve my task do some event when my time equal to current?

Comment: use [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for showing Toast from TimerTask Thread

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0

Comment: And after the FATAL EXCEPTION, does it say anything else? If you want us to help, please include the **full** stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Update ui on the UI Thread. Display toast message on the ui thread.

Just add   the below where you display toast.

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //update ui here
         {
          public void run() 
          {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Now it equels!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
         });
```

Example of timer task

```
_t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         //do something
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //update ui here
         {
          public void run() 
          {
         //display toast here.
          }
         });
    }
}, 1000, 1000 );
```